# SocketException was unhandled exception when building Selenium WebDriver with C# test

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm a new to Selenium WebDriver and just started learning it.

I'm following a tutorial on http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/set-up-selenium-webdriver-with-visual-studio-in-c/

I have a small piece of code for a start:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.Url = "http://www.demoqa.com"; 
}
```

When building it, I'm getting the following exception: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll` on the line `IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

I installed geckpdriver.exe in the project through `NuGet Package Manager` also after a few suggestions I found on google. But, still cannot make it to build.

What am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you're beyond this now, however I found your question while looking for help with the exact same error and tutorial.  For anyone else searching for the same thing, I had to run my VS session as admin and suddenly no error.